# How can I make my 3G USB adapter work?

Tags: 12.04, 3g

I own a 3G USB adapter (DIGISOL DG-BA3370). When I plug it in, the green led lights up,  but I cannot use it.

It works fine in Windows XP. Being a Ubuntu fan, want to use the same here.

Kindly let me know the setup/configuration/work around to use the same on Ubuntu.

I have TATA Docomo 3G GSM sim used in the that device.

Comment: what have you tried so far? plug'n'play does not work? network manager detects 3g-modems automatically. if it does not, you should provide more information.

Comment: One idea: some 3G sticks come with "dual mode" - they act like a CD when starting - I need to issue `eject sr1` every time I plug it in - type `tailf /var/log/syslog` to watch what happens.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10   ...Dongle is detected 3g modem mass storage (2.31)...Please let me know if further info is required.

Comment: MTS Mblaze dongle can be used very easily, by creating a new mobile broadband network, and I have created Mobile broadband network for this, But still this  Digisol 3G dongle is not detected !!

Answer (score 0):

This guide should help you to install your 3d adapter on Ubuntu 12.10: https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/30033514/dg-ba3370-ubuntu-installation-guide-digisolcom

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Download the Drivers for Digisol DG-BA3370 "here is the link"http://www.mediafire.com/download/sps96np8mputo8p/DG-BA3370%28www.bloggerwhist.com%29.zip

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: that link is for windows [ .exe file ], dont download it